# SSRS 2005 Table Border Problems When Rendering to HTML

Tags: reporting-services

I have a problem with my matrix not rendering properly in HTML. It's a minor issue but annoying nonetheless.
The problem is that the right borders disappear on the rightmost column. It only happens on cells with data in them. Like so:

[alt text http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/7718/med100width.png](http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/7718/med100width.png)

Does anyone else experience this? Workarounds? Fixes? Does SSRS 2008 have the same issue?

Comment: Yes, a lot, along with many other issues - using Internet Explorer of any version, even 8 and 9 and 10. Not to mention the (probably)  intentional incompatibility with other browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had similar problems, particularly cross browser, with SSRS. The standard of the HTML generated is very poor and hence often is quirky to say the least even in internet explorer.

The client I was working for had strict standards for accessibility and browser compatibility so I looked into improving the standard of what was outputted a lot but didn't get anywhere. As reports are basically XML I was hoping someone somewhere may have written a better engine to transform this into XHTML but it appears not.

I ended up playing around with table size and column widths which in some cases seemed to resolve some of my issues.

Comment: Sorry for not accepting the answer sooner... I haven't had time to visit the specific client's site since asking the question so I haven't been able to try you suggest solution. But I reckon it's a possible way to go forward and I can always retract the acceptance if it turns out to be fail.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further inspection it seems that all numbers are enclosed in divs, with the attribute width=100%. Using the developer tool in IE I saw that removing width=100% restored the borders.

One solution could be to write your own renderer based on the standard html and filter out the annoying little buggers.

Comment: But that's incorrect. The actual problem is that in Quirksmode, a border-width of 0.25, which is > 0px will be 1px. But in standards-mode, a border < 0.5px is rounded down to 0px, which is the same as NO BORDER, since 1px is the "smallest unit of rendering".